# jquery/ajax submit on correct section of file using switch statment

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

My issue is as follows, I am trying submit a form via jquery and ajax in a file that has switch statements and function for different sections of the file.
When executing the form and jquery it is changing the switch back to the default page, my code is as follows

do.php is a different file which does not need a GET variable 
Switch statement:

```
switch($_GET['action']) {
    case 'page2' :
        page2();
        break;
    default :
        index();
        break;
}
```

Javascript:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $("#form").submit(function() {
      event.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "do.php",
            data: { c: $("#id").val()},
            success: function() {
                alert('test');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Form:

```
<form id='form'>
    <input type='hidden' id='id' value='".$r['cID']."' />
    <td><input type='submit' value ='Submit/></td>
</form>
```

My form and Javascript is part of the function `page2()`

Comment: Do you feel that by omitting what's inside the `page2()` and `index()` functions irrelevant? if it's PHP related (do.php), use error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and look at your console and HTML source and `var_dump()`. You may have to use a `<button>` instead of an input also.

Comment: At `php` `switch` expression is `$_GET['action']` though `$.ajax()` `type` is `POST` ?

Comment: @Fred-ii- You can use whatever element you want to submit the form. A button is no more valid or useful in this context...

Comment: There is no other issue in the page2() file the rest off the code is a while loop to bring the data for r['cid'] which is working perfect, no errors are shown and no errors within the console log either, and yes @guest271314 that is for something different of you look further in the ajax script it is posting to another page

Comment: inputs and buttons behave differently when used with jQuery @MatthewDarnell - *Two different animals altogether*. Inputs will cause pages to redirect in certain instances.

Comment: @AdamHull _"that is for something different of you look further in the ajax script it is posting to another page"_ ? At Question `$.ajax()` uses `POST` though `php` appears to evaluate `GET` request ?

Comment: Where I am excuting the jquery and ajax is http://website.com/page.php?action=page2 this is where the GET variable is coming from and this is the page I am trying to stay on, the ajax call is going to do.php which requires a POST variable

Comment: If do.php is a different PHP file, than nothing in your Javascript will interact with the PHP in your question. PHP is server side code, so it will render your page into HTML and then it's done.

Nothing in the javascript can `change the switch back` unless you are completely reloading the page.

Comment: @Fred -ii- that is absolutely not true. A button type=submit and and input type=submit with both submit forms the same, and nothing about using and input or a button will inherently redirect a page on its own. The type=submit is what causes the element to submit the form, and it's best practice to include one or the other as your submit button for accessibility.

Comment: @MatthewDarnell Funny what the OP posted as an answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/35942775/ - "button". Gee, I wonder why ;-) Edit:Ok... is he posting an answer or asking a question(?) lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed by using buttons and removing the `<form>` these tags where what was causing the file to go to `page.php?` Instead

Comment: Funny what an input and button will do, *huh?* ;-)

Comment: Please do not use answers to ask clarifying questions.

Comment: yeah not sure if this is an answer or a question here Sam @JayBlanchard

Comment: It was the answer the url was page.php? Wasn't a question

Comment: @AdamHull as in what, `page.php?param=123` type of thing? It's unclear what you're trying to convey ;-)

Comment: @AdamHull Ok, never mind. I see what you mean. I didn't see the `<form>` in your answer, since you didn't highlight the `<form>` tag with ticks `\``. I edited it for you.

Comment: Sorry yes that's what I was getting at

Comment: @AdamHull No problemo. Matthew was arguing with me in comments that the input wasn't the problem. Well, it was "a" problem and I said that inputs and buttons react differently, but he says they don't. Well... I think I know what I was talking about ;-)